# Vue.js method PUT working but method GET not in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, get

I have an app in Vue.js which it is working with the method PUT, but the method GET is not working. All the app is working, but  I need that the cabs that I insert in MongoDB show in a table thanks the template of the Vue component.

Component VUE. I only show the part of the table when it should show the data of the MongoDB

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Target</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Driver</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="cab of cabs" :key="cab._id">
                        <td>{{ cab.target }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cab.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cab.driver }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>          
  </template>

<script>
    class Cab{
        constructor(target, price, driver){
            this.target = target;
            this.price = price;
            this.driver = driver;
        }
    }
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                cab: new Cab(),
                cabs: []
            }
        },

        mounted(){
            this.listCabs();
        },
        
        methods:{
            listCabs(){   
                fetch('api/cabs') 
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.cabs = data;
                    console.log(this.cabs);      
               })            
            },
```

And the file index.js in router carpet where is the method GET and method POST

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Cab = require('../models/cab');


router.post('/', async (req, res) =>{
   const cab = new Cab(req.body);
   await cab.save();
   res.json({
       status: 'Cab upload'
   });
});


router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{
    const cabs = await Cab.find();
    res.json(cabs);
    });
    
     
module.exports = router;
```

I dont understand why it is not working

I expect that the show the data from MongoDB in Vue component.

Comment: "it is not working" isn't enough information for others to help with.  There is a long chain of steps in what you're trying to do and it would be very helpful to narrow it down to a specific problem area if possible: does the method `listCabs` on the frontend execute? Does a network request get made? Does the backend receive any request?  Does the mongodb return any data? Does the frontend receive any response? A lot of these questions can be answered by just adding console.logs and seeing what gets hit.

Comment: 1. Mongodb receive data from a form, but method GET not send to the frontend         2. The request is: ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2023:15:44:19 +0000] "POST /api/cabs HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "http://localhost:3000/taxifleet" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"  and ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2023:15:44:19 +0000] "GET /api/cabs HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:3000/taxifleet" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"

Answer (score 0):

Check your method `listCabs`. You are providing a function where you reference `this`, but `this` is no longer what you think it is inside the callback function. Because you are using an arrow function `this` should refer to the gobal `Window` object in this context.

If you had used a normal function declaration instead of a arrow-function, `this` would refer to the function and also not the `vm`.
You should do some research on this topic to fully understand why this is.

Anyway the solution is to create a new Variable binding to the `vm` (aka *closure*) before starting to fetch. And then refer to the ViewModel using the newly created `vm` variable.

Your code should work with this update:

```js
listCabs(){   
    const vm = this
    return fetch('api/cabs') 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        vm.cabs = data;
        console.log(vm.cabs);      
   })            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful, but is not a valid solution. I wil continue working on it.